# How to use ion-footer along with ion-tab in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

When I use both ion-footer and ion-tab at the same time with tab position as bottom. footer does not show in the app when I have both elements visible. Please advice how can I fix this?

Comment: so is the tab supposed to appear on top of footer?

Comment: No, tab is supposed to appear below the footer

Answer (score 0):

I got answer. I have override the ionic toolbar class as follows:

`.toolbar { 
min-height:44px ! important; 
}`